# dispatch_apply submit block to main queue occasionally

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

I have the following code:

```
dispatch_apply(10, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(size_t index) {
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:index];
    NSLog(@"sleep %lu, in thread %@",index,[NSThread currentThread]);
});
```

When run it in main thread, it prints in console:

```
2017-08-14 15:24:53.812 TestGCD[21480:4127352] sleep 0, in thread <NSThread: 0x600000067d40>{number = 1, name = main}
2017-08-14 15:24:54.816 TestGCD[21480:4127420] sleep 1, in thread <NSThread: 0x600000072100>{number = 3, name = (null)}
2017-08-14 15:24:55.816 TestGCD[21480:4127435] sleep 2, in thread <NSThread: 0x600000072180>{number = 4, name = (null)}
2017-08-14 15:24:56.815 TestGCD[21480:4127422] sleep 3, in thread <NSThread: 0x6080000731c0>{number = 5, name = (null)}
2017-08-14 15:24:57.813 TestGCD[21480:4127352] sleep 4, in thread <NSThread: 0x600000067d40>{number = 1, name = main}
2017-08-14 15:24:59.818 TestGCD[21480:4127420] sleep 5, in thread <NSThread: 0x600000072100>{number = 3, name = (null)}
2017-08-14 15:25:01.822 TestGCD[21480:4127435] sleep 6, in thread <NSThread: 0x600000072180>{number = 4, name = (null)}
2017-08-14 15:25:03.821 TestGCD[21480:4127422] sleep 7, in thread <NSThread: 0x6080000731c0>{number = 5, name = (null)}
2017-08-14 15:25:05.815 TestGCD[21480:4127352] sleep 8, in thread <NSThread: 0x600000067d40>{number = 1, name = main}
2017-08-14 15:25:08.824 TestGCD[21480:4127420] sleep 9, in thread <NSThread: 0x600000072100>{number = 3, name = (null)}
```

I find that in "sleep 0,4,8" the current thread is main thread.

```
sleep 0, in thread <NSThread: 0x600000067d40>{number = 1, name = main}
```

Why I submit the block to a global queue but it's called on main queue occasionally ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This log suggests that you must have called `dispatch_apply` from the main thread.

1. When you say that you "submit the block to a global queue", make sure you dispatch the call to `dispatch_apply` to the global queue, too, because this is a synchronous API.
2. When you dispatch the `dispatch_apply` to some background queue, make sure you use `dispatch_async`. If you use `dispatch_sync` it can use the current thread, as an optimization.

What you want is:

```
NSLog(@"starting on thread %@",[NSThread currentThread]);

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    dispatch_apply(10, dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_DEFAULT, 0), ^(size_t index) {
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:index];
        NSLog(@"sleep %lu, in thread %@",index,[NSThread currentThread]);
    });
});
```

Note, I'm using `dispatch_async` and I'm putting the `dispatch_apply` inside the dispatched block, not the other way around.

Comment: You should probably clarify the difference between threads and queues.  A task dispatched on the main queue *will always execute on the main thread*. A task dispatched on another queue *may execute on the main thread*. Examining the current thread cannot tell you anything about the queue that the task was dispatched on. (Well, I suppose if the current thread isn't the main thread then you know the task wasn't dispatched on the main queue)

Comment: IMHO, there are two salient points: First, code dispatch synchronously to some queue will actually run on the current thread whenever possible (e.g. thus if you call `dispatch_sync` to a global queue from the main thread, the dispatched task will run on the main thread, regardless). Second, when you do `dispatch_apply` (which is synchronous), the current thread "participates". So if you `dispatch_apply` from the main thread, the main thread will be one of the threads it uses.